# Draw real BI 3D cube

Tags: business-intelligence, olap, cube

I am trying to find a program / software which can help me to produce a real 3D Business Intelligence OLAP cube... not just to create the cube with simply data but have the real cube produced i.e. a visualisation of the cube.

Anyone knows what software / programs I can use please?

Comment: Not sure if I  understand you correctly. OLAP allows to have unlimited dimensions. How can you fit unlimited dimensions in just a 3D space?

The only possible way I know of is making "slices" of the cube and presenting these in 2D or 3D tables/ charts.

I can help you with the latter, but as stated, I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what "real 3D ... OLAP cube" means.

Real-life OLAP cubes have usually more than 3 dimensions and the visualizations are usually made with 2D charts/tables (note that those charts/tables can display more than 2 cube dimensions). Using a 3D charts is quite unusual because not easy to read (being 3D means certains parts of the charts are hidden).

Now there might be some usecases where a 3D rendering would be nice. For example, at [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) a customer requested to have MDX results displayed  over his 3D rendered retail shop. For that purpose, we did a plugin using [three.js](http://threejs.org/) that mapped the result of the MDX request to several items in the shop; quite nice actually but quite specific to its usecase.

That being said, I've seen a sort of 3D barchart (sorry cannot remember the link) in the past but this was not successful as you had to "move" the chart to check for hidden values at the 'back' (no way to know before looking at the back).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don t know if I explained my self well... I mean to have this cube to present it in a presentation where I would like to have a visualisation of the cube and if I click on a specific part of the cube, the relevant information is shown...